# How to access title text property of an NSNotification swift

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

Is there a simple way to access the alert title text sent in an NSNotification? (This example from a Notification action)

Here is the JSON Notification

```
{
"alert": "This is the text I want to capture",
"string": "12345"
"badge": "Increment",
"sound": "chime",
"category": "ACTION_CATEGORY"
}
```

Here is the method in App delegate to post notification to NSNotification centre

```
// handle the action once pressed in the notification
    func application(application: UIApplication,
                    handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?,
                    forRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                    completionHandler: () -> Void) {

       let string = userInfo["string"] as! String

        if identifier == "VIEW_IDENTIFIER" {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationActionPressed", object: nil, userInfo:["string": "\(string)"])
       // userInfo can be accessed from any VC observing the notification
        }
        completionHandler() //dont forget this!  
    }
```

Here is the observer in ViewDidLoad in my HomeVC

```
// check for saved notifications
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(HomeViewController.showString(_:)), name: "NotificationActionPressed", object: nil)
```

and here is the show method called when the observer observes.

```
var string: String!

func showString(notification: NSNotification) {

let userInfo:Dictionary<String,String!> = notification.userInfo as! Dictionary<String,String!>
string = userInfo["string"]
// now do something else e.g show an alert.
}
```

Comment: You don't pass any information as either the object or user info with your "NotificationActionPressed" notification, so I don't see how you expect to extract anything from it.

Comment: Thanks Phillip. I can see that now. Have edited code above to show working solution from a notification action, passing the string to HomeVC. Thanks again.